# How can you grab elements in dom and apply different css without id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am bit confused here.
I am working on a dynamic project and I want to apply different css to 
divs which have same class but no id. 
How can I apply different css say to first div with same class, and then 
different css to second div of same class and so on...
Let's say I have `fullwidthContainer` class applied to **3** `divs`
For the first div, I want width `1000px`, to the second I want **800px** and so on.
**I can not give an id or another class here since it's dynamically generated**.
Please help.

Thanks.

Ok i did this using javascript

```
  function emphatic()
{
    var totalContainers=document.getElementsByClassName('fullwidthContainer')
    var className=1;

    for (var i = 0; i < totalContainers.length; i++) {
        className=className+1;
        totalContainers[i].setAttribute("class", "dropdown_5columns fullwidthContainer customMenuClass");
    };

}
emphatic();
```

Now how do i append classname with 1 added everytime to the new class.
**i mean something like customclass1, customclass2 and so on to divs.. thanks,**

Comment: simple concatenation for the incremental class names based on `i`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the element indexes although it's not entirely clear if you have relationships to match:

Example using increments based on index:

```
$('.someClass').each(function(index){
  $(this).width( 300 * (index+1) );
});
```

Example using array:

```
var widths =[ 600, 900, 500];

$('.someClass').each(function(index){
  $(this).width( widths[index] );
});
```

Array version could also be adapted to add classes.

Index starts at zero being first matching element in page

Comment: please see my question again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're aslo interested in a pure javascript solution.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
var width = [100,200,300];
for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
    divs[i].style.width = width[i] + 'px';
    // increases classname by i
    divs[i].className = 'myClass anotherClass' + i;
}
```

Comment: thank you, thank you, thank you, for providing pure a javascript solution. I always aim to provide such solutions but I alone is not enough to battle the ever growing, unnecessary jQuery answers.

Comment: Seems that I've joined forces :)